# How to get the secrets from Azure Key Vault Using Azure SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-keyvault, ssis-2012

How to get the secrets from AKV using Azure SQL Query or any other methods to make a connection string for SSIS?

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable Managed Identity on your Azure SQL DB.
2. Make an HTTP request to the MSI endpoint to get an access token for Key Vault.
3. Using the access token, make another HTTP call to the Key Vault for the secret you want.